# exercise: download queue in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm slowly learning Bash. I have the basic idea in mind, but I need the right syntax and putting things together. Was hoping someone here could help.

As an exercise, I am using a downloading queue tool, which is based on youtube-dl.

the script asks the user for a link. It takes the link, and stores it in link1. It increase the link count by one after each entry. As long as the user puts in links, variables are created (link1, link2 .... so on) and n, the number of links increase by one. When user hits "q", the loop exists and the script executes.

Something like this:

```
n=0
echo "enter your link. when done, press 'd' "
read link
n++

for $n 
do: youtube-dl link & wait; 
else 
 if user presses d, this loop should terminate
```

I know this is very vague, but was hoping I could get some guidance.

It's something like that. I can't wrap my head around it fully. Can someone maybe point me in the right direction?

Comment: Would advise you to put in the script to show what you have written and tried so far and post it on [CodeReview StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) for better answers.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus But only if it's a working script, looking for a review. Non-working code is off-topic on CodeReview.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you, try something like this. You don't really need the counter $n, since you can just add to an array and then loop through it just the same, without having to keep track of the size yourself. Of course instead of the echo $str you would want to add your own code there with the link.

```
input=""
arr=()
while [ "$input" != "q" ]
do
    read -p "Gimmy some input, 'q' to quit: "  input
    if [ "$input" != "d" ]
    then
        arr+=($input)
    fi
done

for str in ${arr[@]}
do
    echo "$str"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for that, ok getting closer. some questions for you: 

read -p (means, read command after the following "echo", which follows) " input (this part means, put it into input) -- is that correct? that's pretty cool.

arr+=($input) -- this means, increase array arr by input? how does that work, input would be URL (the command is, yourtube-dl "URL here") 

and I'm not sure what the last part is for.. still lost but this is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: You should put all the variable references in double-quotes, e.g. `arr+=("$input")` and `for str in "${arr[@]}"`.

Comment: using an array makes sense, since I have a bunch of URLs. so, it's youtube-dl URL1, youtube-dl URL2, youtube-dl URL3 etc. I get that... hm. but the command needs to be something like youtube-dl "(location in array #1)" & wait; youtube-dl "(location in array #2)" $ wait; ... makes sense?

Comment: @JRSS: `somecommand & wait` is unnecessary -- the `&` makes it run the command in the background (i.e. not wait for it before continuing), but the `wait` then immediately waits for it. They cancel each other out! Just run the command directly and it'll automatically wait for it to finish before continuing.

Comment: @JRSS: No, the `&`s will make it run the first two commands in the background (i.e. not wait for them). You need to leave out both the `&` and the `wait`. Use `command ; command ; command` (or just put each command on a separate line and omit the semicolons) and it'll run the commands in sequence.